# Printing text causes memory issue

Tags: c++

I am doing a program to solve matrixes and when I was trying to debug I wrote code like that:

```
double* row = matrix[i];
int first_nz = get_first_nz_el_idx(row, size);
cout << row[first_nz];
```

And the funny thing is, when I put that cout instruction there, my results completly change, it starts to return random, big numbers, like `01.55e+2311`. When I delete that cout instruction, results are correct. I could work-around that problem somehow, but I want to know what's the reason of this behavior. Also, when I do '`cout << "anything";` it's the same issue. But when I call other function like `pow(3, 2)` - its nothing wrong.

There is the function, which sums some elements in a row passed:

```
double sum_nz_el(double* row, int size)
{
    int first = get_first_nz_el_idx(row, size) + 1;
    int last = size - 1;
    double sum;
    if (first > size - 2)
        return 0;
    while (first < last)
    {
        sum += row[first];
        first++;
    }
    return sum;
}

int get_first_nz_el_idx(double* row, int size)
{
    int i = size - 2;
    while (!(row[i - 1] == 0 || i == 0))
        i--;
    return i;
}
```

And when I do `cout << row[first_nz]` or `cout << sum_nz_el(row, size)` (it doesn't really matter which one, problem appears in both cases), the function sum_nz_el starts to return random, big numbers, when that row is passed. It should be like max 2,5

Row could be like that:
`0 0 0 23 41 11`

Comment: You aren't initializing `sum`.  This leads to undefined behavior.  Variables are not initialized to zero by default in C++.

Comment: sum is initialized to 0 automatically, so it's not a big deal

Comment: @Ginko -- Sum in **not** initialized automatically.  It is a local variable, thus it contains any random garbage, and yes, 0 is just as random as any other garbage value.

Comment: It's a weird thing. Initializing sum to 0 solved it somehow, but it produces the same result as if I wouldn't do this, although it now works regardless of putting that cout instruction

Comment: @Ginko -- It is not weird.  A local variable in C++ starts out with random junk if not initialized.  Without initialization, it could be 0, -1, 4325, 89, -67, you don't know.  Sticking a `cout` line only changes the binary image, thus you get some other trash value as the starting value.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I mean that, when I don't initialize sum, it starts with 0 if I don't print anything before creating sum. Otherwise it becomes a huge, random number.

Comment: @Ginko I don't know what other computer languages you've used before, but C++ has something called **undefined behavior**.  It is *not* weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is this line:

`double sum;`

This variable is local, thus uninitialized.  It starts out with a garbage value.  That garbage value can be anything, including 0. Also, you can't predict what the garbage value may be, or even "control it" by removing or adding irrelevant lines of code (like the `cout` statement you mentioned).

To fix this issue, all you need is to simply initialize the variable:

```
double sum = 0.0;
```

Also, you don't need that loop if you used the algorithm function [std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

```
#include <numeric>
//..
double sum_nz_el(double* row, int size)
{
    int first = get_first_nz_el_idx(row, size) + 1;
    int last = size - 1;
    if (first > size - 2)
       return 0;
    return std::accumulate(row + first, row + last, 0.0);
}
```

Comment: It would be great to know how the cout statement affects the garbage value of the uninitialised local 'sum'. It's not clear to me. Though I guess that's another question.

Comment: By adding or removing lines of code (it does not have to be the `cout` line), you're changing the executable image.  Change the compiler options, and you yet again may see differing behavior.